# How can I read in a file with multiple x, y coordinates pairs and display as scatter points in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file consist of multiple x,y coordinates pairs/columns :

614749.4    471134.6    614682.35   470996.6

614755.6    471134.1    614685.45   470996.4

614761.8    471133.5    614688.55   470996.1

614768.1    471133      614691.7    470995.85

.......

614767.6    471058.1    614691.45   470958.4

614773.8    471057.6    614694.55   470958.15

614780      471057.1    614697.65   470957.9

614786.2    471056.6    614700.75   470957.65

I would like to use Python to read in the file and display it like what excel can do:

The file could be very big with million of x,y pairs. Excel is too slow to read and display the scatter points. I have numpy and matplotlib package installed. I have trouble to

Answer (score 0):

Last year I had to deal with lots of data and fit it too. So I had written a simple code to do all that. Hope it helps you in some way. You can contact me if needed.

[UNDERFed](http://github.com/SamD97/UNDERFed) This is the link for the code.

It takes up all the files in a given directory and process the data file by file plots it and fits it with your given function if required and at the end, results are stored in a text file.

you can write something yourself using numpy and matplotlib libraries. you need to use numpy genfromtxt to get the data into a multi-dimensional array and then plot it using matplotlib.